# Algorithm: Minimum number of Transanctions

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

**Statement**: There are 4 guys: A, B, C & D. They owe some amount of money among each other.

1. A to give 200 bucks to B.
2. A to give 400 bucks to C.
3. B to give 100 bucks to C.
4. B to give 300 bucks to A.
5. C to give 300 bucks to D.
6. D to give 500 bucks to B

.

There are 6 transactions to be made. There is no dealing of money from outside.

**Problem**: Minimize the number of transactions. For example, the above 6 transactions can be reduced to 2 transactions:

1. A gives 300 bucks to B.
2. D gives 200 bucks to C.

I am looking for a generic and efficient approach for this.